# Is it necessary to update the Report Viewer Redistributable from 2012 to 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

Apparently, reports (RDLC files) created with Visual Studio 2015:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

use the same schema as those created with Visual Studio 2012:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

They seem to be "compatible", i.e., I can open an RDLC file created with Visual Studio 2012 in Visual Studio 2015 - it is not necessary to convert it to a new format (as was the case with older Visual Studio versions).

Does that mean that I can use the (old) Report Viewer 2012 Redistributable (which is already installed on my customers' PCs) to render reports created with Visual Studio 2015 or do I need to upgrade my customers to Report Viewer 2015 Redistributable?

Answer (score 2):

RDLC is short for Report Definition Language for Clients and there have been no new RDL Schema Versions released since [`2010 RDL`](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/) which explains why it's "compatible" in Visual Studio 2015.
Even if you plan on using a different schema, you should still be able to render these reports with the Report Viewer 2012.

Source:
[MSDN - Plan for Report Design and Report Deployment (Reporting Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207009.aspx)